# Uniform Local Binary Pattern Histogram

Tags: c++, image-processing, histogram

I`m working at a project and I have to implement Local Binary Pattern histograms for an image.
I would like to use Uniform Local Binary Pattern.

0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,12,14,15,16,24,28,30,31,32,48,56,60,62,63,64,96,112,120,124,126,127,128,129,131,135,143,159,191,192,193,195,199,207,223,224,225,227,231,239,240,241,243,247,248,249,251,252,253,254,255

These are the values for uniform binary patterns.There are 58 such patterns,but I read that an uniform local binary pattern histogram has the size 59.So I will consider just uniform patterns (58) ,but how I compute the 59-th element of histogram?
Please help!
Thank you !
PS(I`m not interested in an open cv function to solve this,I just want to understand how I compute this histogram.)

Answer (score 0):

Read the wikipedia entry on local binary patterns

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns

You have to split the input into cells, you then derive a number for each pixel in the cell, depending on whether it is larger or smaller than its 8-connected neighbours. That gives you 256 possible values, but we filter by only considering pixels where there are at most two 0-1 transitions (thus excluding checkerboard type patterns). That's why not all values appear in your table, and I would guess that you are expected to use the last index to store all non-"uniform" values.

Comment: "I would guess that you are expected to use the last index to store all non-"uniform" values. " Yes, I will count all non uniform patterns on that position , am I right?

Comment: Exactly. In a non-contrived, non-dithered image, it should be rare for there to be more than one 0-1 transition as you got round the target pixel in a circle. The few exceptions you simply store in their own bin at the end.